# Setting up a virtual Com Port?

Tags: windows-7, usb, serial-port, barcode, com-port

What I need to get to work together:

- A USB barcode scanner
- A Windows (7) Machine
- A piece of software that listens for data over a COM port

So I believe I need a way to make USB device appear to be a serial one. Several caveats have lead me to this point. The computer has no serial ports. The software allows (and is a needed feature) for multiple devices so even if it did have serial ports it wouldn't have enough.

I can't quite find the right or workable answer on my own. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Describe your "caveats."

Comment: You might be able to use [`com0com`](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) as one piece of an overall solution, though you'd need a program to provide an interface between the USB and TCP.

Comment: @Steven A bad choice of punctuation on my part. The fact that I do not have any serial ports to work with and legacy software that requires them combined newer hardware that no longer uses them.

Comment: I guess this might help if the com0com didn't https://www.eltima.com/products/com0com-virtual-port/