# USB Smart Card Reader to COM Port

Tags: windows-10, usb, smartcard, com, com-port

I'm facing the following problem:

I have a software that reads/writes Smart Cards through COM Ports. The Smart Card device that i own is plugged through USB therefore recognised as a usb device with the result of the software not being able to use my USB device.

And i'm asking, is there a solution to map the USB device in a Virtual COM Port ? As i've seen in the device manager there's a COM Port even though there aren't and physical ports in the computer since it's running from a Virtual Machine.

I found this answer here: [How to map a virtual COM port to a physical USB port?](https://superuser.com/questions/923426/how-to-map-a-virtual-com-port-to-a-physical-usb-port) but i can't seem to make it work.

The device i'm using is Omnikey 3021 with Windows 10 and i know for a fact that another company managed to make it work with the exact same software/hardware

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please add an OS tag. The term "virtual com port" suggests some Windows, but I've heard people using it also for other OS, even though those OS don't have "virtual com ports".

Comment: Note that USB does not have a _general_ 1:1 mapping to COM serial – it just so happens that smartcard readers have an USB protocol _and_ a serial protocol so there can be a translator between the two. There should be solutions specific to card-readers, just don't expect just any "virtual com port" solution to work for any kind of USB device.